# what is dependency for Sonar-plugins in POM

Tags: maven, sonarqube

We have upgraded SonarQube from version 3.7.2 to 4.5.5. We are using maven to 
build and deployment.

There are some plugins need to be updated. But, I am not sure whether, I am not able to find the exact GAV parameter for them or to find latest version using POM.

e.g  Build-stability-plugin; I am not able to find version 1.3 for this plugin on maven repository.
Any kind of help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You mix Maven plugins and SonarQube plugins. The latter doesn't need to be deployed in Maven repository nor to be defined in project poms.

Comment: Hi, we are upgrading sonar using maven. we are not directly upgrading on server. Previously with 3.7.3 version we were doing same thing. Since we are upgrading sonar to 4.5.5, I am not able to find right dependency for some plugins. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean by "we are upgrading sonar using maven" ? Or maybe you're talking about the version of sonar-maven-plugin ?

Comment: The plugins required for sonar, we are retrieving them using pom dependency. consider sonar-web-plugin, the version 2.3 is available to retrieve using pom dependency but 2.4 is not available

Comment: You're wrong. SonarQube plugins must not be declared as dependencies of your project.

Comment: Its not dependency but we are using **copy** goal of maven-dependency-plugin. and copying into plugin folder of sonar

Comment: Your message was not clear at all. This is a non-conventional way to update SonarQube. Most of the plugins are not deployed to Maven central repository anymore, so this approach can't work.

Comment: Ok . Thank you. Thats what I wanted. _Most of the plugins are not deployed to Maven central repository anymore_

Comment: Could you please tell me whether http://sonarsource.bintray.com/Distribution is the now official site for to download sonar  plugins